# Enable Picture in Picture mode programmatically

Tags: java, android, picture-in-picture

I'm making a settings activity in my Android video playback app and I want to know if it was possible to enable/disable PIP(Picture-in-Picture) mode programmatically.

To clarify I am fully aware that this setting can be change via application advanced settings or via special app access, but I want to leave that as a last resort. (If there are no other alternatives).

Further more this Activity is isolated from the video threading page itself.(Meaning the user would have to stop the video entirely before coming to this page).

Main reasons I want this is an extra reminder that this app supports this feature and also if the user forgets where to reactivate this function.

Think of it as: Adding another layer of user friendliness

Comment: "I am fully aware that this setting can be change via application advanced settings or via special app access" -- I do not know what you mean by this. You use ordinary APIs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture

Comment: It is exactly as I said earlier,  Users can enable/disable PIP by  Settings - > Apps - > (Our App name) - > Advanced OR Settings -> Special App Access -> Picture-In-Picture

Comment: Your app will appear in that list automatically if you have `android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"` on an activity in the manifest. The user still could go into this Settings screen and disable your PiP access. If so, AFAIK, you do not have a way to change that from the app. I'm not even certain that there is an official way to tell what that setting is.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to check the setting:

```
AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
return (AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED == appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE,
        context.getApplicationInfo().uid, context.getPackageName()));
```

I haven't tried setting it programmatically, but this could be a starting point for you.